# Get URL parameters in Flash

Tags: php, html, flash

I have a url like this

```
www.website.com?fname=Peter
```

and I have a `Dynamic Text` field  as `fnameurl` in my Flash movie and want to show `Peter` in the Dynamic Text field once its opened on a browser. How can I grab the url Parameters and display it on the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to use the [FlashVars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) parameter. It is defined via an HTML `param` tag like this:

```
<param name='flashvars' value='name=value&amp;name2=value2' />
```

The value must be formatted as a URL query string. The indiviual key/value pairs will be made available in the root of the SWF movie. In AS2 you can simply access them using `_root`:

```
_root.name
_root.name2
```

In AS3 these values are available via [`LoaderInfo.parameters`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters):

```
root.loaderInfo.parameters.name
root.loaderInfo.parameters.name2
```

Long story short, you could do it like this in PHP:

```
<param name='flashvars' value='fname=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['fname']); ?>' />
```

and then in AS:

```
fnameurl.text = _root.fname;

// or

fnameurl.text = root.loaderInfo.parameters.fname;
```

Comment: Thanks @ndm. I tried this, but it outputs "Denied". What could be the reason?

Comment: Only the word "Denied"? Maybe your textfield is very small and that's just the last word of a longer error message? Check that, and also have a look the HTML source generated by your PHP file if there are any errors.

Comment: No. There are no errors. I cant see the fname value in my HTML source code, but not sure why it isnt passing to the swf file. I have fnameurl.text = _root.fname; in a movie clip, does that matter? And the fnameurl text field is in the same movieclip

Comment: And there are no other assignemts to `fnameurl.text` in your code? Might sound like a stupid question, but could it be that it actually says `undefined`? Becasue `root.fname` will neither work in AS2 nor in AS3. I assume you are using AS2 since you're not trying to access `loaderInfo`? In that case you are missing an underscore, it should be `_root.fname` In case that's not the problem it would be good if you would show your actual HTML output and AS code.

Comment: The difference is that without `_root` it will try to access a variable in the current scope, ie in your movieclip where your code is located, where as with `_root` it would access a variable in the top most timeline of the SWF movie, ie in the root, where the `FlashVars` variables would be located. So, not using `_root` will only work in case the code in question is defined in the root timeline too. What exactly goes wrong in your movie is pretty hard to say without knowing the exact movie structure, the HTML and AS.